Manhwa or manhua where a kid learning martial arts in a dojo starts jumping between realms
The story begins with a kid who gets adopted by a dojo where he learns martial arts. As the story progresses, it shifts into a game-like adventure, where he seems to jump between different realms. He has a sister who is obsessed with him and relentlessly hunts him down because of his unique abilities.
One the few thing that made it rememberable was the unique art style.
I remember one of the covers showing him with half of his face wrapped in gold, smiling.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?

What was so distinctive about the art style?

I want to say two year ago

The artwork was somewhat similar to the hardcore leveling warrior

I remember that the gold like armor is it kind of look like muscle fibers and I made a quick AI image of what one of the cover look like the artwork is not the same but the detail of the cover is https://imgur.com/a/weUxGoj
